# Sklearn DecisionTreeclassifier returning impossible value for split

Tags: python, pandas, decision-tree, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to implement a DecisionTreeClassifier from sklearn with a DataFrame (pandas), but it returns some weird values when splitting my data. My dataset contains 3 columns with Pearsons Correlation coefficients, which can be only between -1.0 and 1.0. The root node, however, already starts splitting by one of these columns at Pearsons <= 1.0 and shows two child nodes for True and False. But, it's impossible!! All the values are <= 1.0. There's no way that a split could have been made there. Does anyone has any idea what is going on here?

In my code I tried both Gini and Entropy criterion, both splitters and other different combinations of the possible Parameters. Here is more or less my code now, but I'm still playing around with the Parameters:

```
newtable = table_of_pickle_ptptnew.loc[:,('Pearsons Ratio', 'Pearsons 330nm', 'Pearsons 350nm', 'Ratio Space', '330nm Similarity', '350nm Similarity')]

x = newtable.values
y = table_of_pickle_ptptnew['Binding Known'].values

dtree=DecisionTreeClassifier(max_features='auto',
                             max_depth=3,
                             criterion ='entropy',
                             min_impurity_decrease=0.09
                            )
fittree = dtree.fit(x, y.astype('str'))

dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(fittree, out_file=None,
                               class_names=['No Interaction', 'Interaction'],
                               feature_names=['Pearsons Ratio', 'Pearsons 330nm', 'Pearsons 350nm', 'Ratio Space', '330nm Similarity', '350nm Similarity'],
                               filled=True) 
graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data) 
graph



          Pearsons Ratio    Pearsons 330nm  Pearsons 350nm  Ratio Space     330nm Similarity    350nm Similarity
Elem a     0.94856          0.99999         0.99999        0.000725507      0.157209             0.0572688
Elem b     0.99234          1               0.99999        0.00657003       0.0568281            0.0465139
Elem c     0.98525          0.99999         0.99999        0.0114932        0.0226809            0.133452
Elem d     0.99793          0.99999         0.99999        0.000643209      0.154585             0.0914759
Elem e     0.99849          0.99999         0.99999        0.00128532       0.0932893            0.0464462
```

Here is how the first nodes of the tree looks like. So, what I mean is that the child node for **False** in the condition of the root node (Pearson 350nm <= 1.0) is **impossible** to exist, since all samples are <= 1.0 (True).

[image: Condition tree piece.]

Comment: Just for clarification, Pearson's correlation coefficient in general can take values between -1 and 1, but your data only contains values between 0 and 1?

Comment: No sorry, my bad. It's from -1 to 1, correct. I'll correct it in the question.

Comment: One possible idea is that you rescaled the features, but it does not seem to be the case from the code snippet. Btw, the graph also shows how many samples satisfied the given chain of conditions, is this number really 0 for the False?

Comment: No... Both child nodes for True/False gives samples satisfying the condition. That's my problem there. If I implement this in my real code, it's not going to work because I know that no value can be higher than 1.0. Right now, it gives me [7,53] for True and [34,7] for False... :/

Comment: Could you post 5 to 10 rows from your newtable.

Comment: I added a piece of it in the edited question now

Comment: It works fine. I think you are misinterpreting the decision tree. The [7, 53] and [34, 7] are the numbers of positive and negative samples in each leaf, not the criterion for splitting. I can show you what I got with your data if necessary.

Comment: you don't understand I guess... The root node parameter is like "Pearsons Ratio >= 1.0" and then, there are the two node child, for true and false... but this condition can never be true... still, there are [7, 53] in the corresponding True child node - 7 of class A and 53 of class B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I found out what was the problem.
The graphviz visualization of the tree has a limit to the decimal numbers and round them if too large. I used a algorithm to give me the pseudo-code for my decision tree automatically and in the code output the 'true values' showed up. In the graphical tree from graphviz the 1.0 from the root node is actually '0.9999749660491943'.

I think it's important to know this for everyone that is working with scientific numbers that have a great deal of digits. :) If you work with numbers like this, remember to get the decision code from your tree and don't go only for the pretty colorful tree.

Thank you to everyone that used a bit of their time to try to help me with my issue. :)